# how can i connect my previous clash of clan to google play services

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I wanted to save my clash of clan.
Because I have to transffered it to a android tab.it's always appear a qoute that" incompatible with other application using a same shared id.how can I fix it?

Comment: You can try using that quote into Google search. It should lead you to something conclusive which you can share with us as your search/research.

Answer (score 0):

Binding your clash of clans to a gmail account. Then you just need to open your clash of clans in other device with that gmail account